# Android: Add image to raw folder

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set an image in gallery as a wallpaper using WallpaperManager but the setResource() excepts only images from the raw folder. And therefore I want to access the desired image and hence store it into the raw folder and use it to set the wallpaper.

I am using :

```
 buttonSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    myWallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
                    myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.raw.batman_480_800);  // batman_480_800 is image in raw folder
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wallpaper set successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Some error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I need to know how can I add an image to raw folder and hence access it to set as wallpaper. Or there is any other way to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity Declare Global

```
 private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
```

Use Intent for select image from device gallery

```
buttonSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
Intent intent = new Intent();
// Show only images, no videos or anything else
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
// Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

 });
}
```

get selected image then convert into bit map and set as wall paper

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

    Uri uri = data.getData();

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri); 
        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jus create /res/raw/ folder and move the resources to it. And load with  `myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.raw.imageResource);`